# Existence of limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{[n/2]} \frac 1 n f \left(\frac i n \right)$!

Tags: limits, integration

> If $f$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ then $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{[n/2]} \frac 1 n f \left(\frac i n \right)$$ (where $[y]$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $y$)
>
> (A) does not exist
>
> (B) exists and is equal to $\displaystyle \frac 1 2 \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\, dx $
>
> (C) exists and is equal to $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\, dx $
>
> (D) exists and is equal to $\displaystyle  \int_{0}^{1/2} f(x)\, dx $

Trial: Let $m=n/2$. So, we have $\displaystyle \lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{[m]} \frac 1 {2m} f \left(\frac i {2m} \right)$. Then I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: Answer D is correct, [see this thread][1].


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375011/integration-as-limit-of-a-sum/375075#375075

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: I post a answer with help of your thread. Am I right?.Please see. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here $\displaystyle a_n=\sum_{j=0}^{[\frac n2]}\frac 1nf\left(\frac jn\right)$. Again $$a_{2m}=\frac 12\frac 1m\sum_{j=0}^{[m]}f\left(\frac 12\frac jm\right),$$
Hence $\displaystyle \lim_{m\to +\infty}a_{2m}=\frac 12\int_0^1f\left(\frac x2\right)dx$.

So, let $y=x/2$ then we have  $\displaystyle \lim_{m\to +\infty}a_{2m}=\int_0^{1/2}f(y)\,dy$.

Hence choice $(D)$ is correct.

Comment: What you prove is that the subsequence $(a_{2m},m\geqslant 1)$ converges to the required limit. At least, it helps you to see which answer is correct. But you also have to show that the subsequence $(a_{2m+1},m\geqslant 1)$ converges to the same limit.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: Thank you again. Now I fully understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the definition of the Riemann Integral?